# Why do clone troopers punch droids?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

I have seen at least two instances so far: that trooper at the Battle of Christophsis, and Cut Lawquane. Yes, they both happened to have lost their firearm but why do they punch the enemy droid in response? Punching a metal droid simply makes the clone's hand hurt badly enough to distract him long enough for the droid to retaliate.

During the battle at the Rishi Station, Rex demonstrated how to take down a commando droid in melee combat. Are most clones not trained in how to properly engage an enemy droid in melee combat, or are they indeed trained in doing something as ridiculous as punching metal with your own hand?

Comment: Probably works better than shooting them for stormtroopers

Comment: Their hands are armored, and the droids look like they're made from cheap materials, despite Dooku saying "Those droids are expensive".

Comment: @CBredlow watching Clone Wars right now, actually. There was a scene where a Clone punches a regular battle droid and breaks his wrist (final episodes of season 2 or start season 3, not sure, I am blitzing through the episodes).

Answer (score 5):

**It's probably just a heat of the moment thing.**

You're a clone trooper.  You're in the middle of a giant battle with the evil droids, and you've lost your gun.  You've been trained on how to defeat a droid in melee combat, but you just can't quite remember. The droid is coming at you, getting closer and closer...

The troopers probably just had no time to think about what to do.  As far as I can tell, this is a common thing for a soldier to do; there's very little time to think in a battle.

Besides, why not punch them?  They've got armor on their hands, and it'll at least surprise the droid, giving you a chance to get your weapon and/or escape.